# load this format into an R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I load an input file like this into an R dataframe?

```
    [S1]     [E1]  |     [S2]     [E2]  |  [LEN 1]  [LEN 2]  |  [% IDY]  | [TAGS]
=====================================================================================
  959335   959806  |      169      640  |      472      472  |    80.84  | LmjF.34      ULAVAL|LtaPseq521
  322990   324081  |     1436      342  |     1092     1095  |    83.86  | LmjF.12      ULAVAL|LtaPseq501
  324083   324327  |      245        1  |      245      245  |    91.84  | LmjF.12      ULAVAL|LtaPseq501
 1097873  1098325  |      892      437  |      453      456  |    76.75  | LmjF.32      ULAVAL|LtaPseq491
 1098566  1098772  |      207        4  |      207      204  |    75.60  | LmjF.32      ULAVAL|LtaPseq491
```

Comment: If the positions of the columns are always the same, i.e., if it is a fixed-width format, you can use `read.fwf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like Fixed Width Formatted data, and can be easily read in with read.fwf - the tricky bit might be getting rid of the | marks. WHat do you want to do with the [TAGS] section?

Here I work out the widths of each field, add some fields (length 3) to skip over the | markers, read it in, then use negative column subsetting to drop the separator columns:

```
> widths=c(8,9,3,9,9,3,9,9,3,9,3,100)
> read.fwf("data.txt",widths=widths,skip=2)[,-c(3,6,9,11)]
       V1      V2   V4  V5   V7   V8   V10                             V12
1  959335  959806  169 640  472  472 80.84  LmjF.34      ULAVAL|LtaPseq521
2  322990  324081 1436 342 1092 1095 83.86  LmjF.12      ULAVAL|LtaPseq501
3  324083  324327  245   1  245  245 91.84  LmjF.12      ULAVAL|LtaPseq501
4 1097873 1098325  892 437  453  456 76.75  LmjF.32      ULAVAL|LtaPseq491
5 1098566 1098772  207   4  207  204 75.60  LmjF.32      ULAVAL|LtaPseq491
```

You might want to split the tags into two columns - just work out the width of each part and add field widths to the widths vector. An exercise for the reader.

Note this only works if the file is spaced out with space characters and NOT tab characters...

Answer (score 1):

Read the file using readLines or Scan

> test <-'    [S1]     [E1]  |     [S2]     [E2]  |  [LEN 1]  [LEN 2]  |
> [% IDY]  | [TAGS]
>
> =====================================================================================
>
> 959335   959806  |      169      640  |      472      472  |    80.84  | LmjF.34      ULAVAL|LtaPseq521
>
> 322990   324081  |     1436      342  |     1092     1095  |    83.86  | LmjF.12      ULAVAL|LtaPseq501
>
> 324083   324327  |      245        1  |      245      245  |    91.84  | LmjF.12      ULAVAL|LtaPseq501
>
> 1097873  1098325  |      892      437  |      453      456  |    76.75  | LmjF.32      ULAVAL|LtaPseq491
>
> 1098566  1098772  |      207        4  |      207      204  |    75.60  | LmjF.32      ULAVAL|LtaPseq491'
>
> test2 <- gsub('|',' ',test, fixed=TRUE)
>
> test2 <- gsub('=','',test2, fixed=TRUE)
>
> test3 <- gsub('[ \t]{2,8}',';',test2,perl=TRUE)
>
> test3 <- gsub('\n','',test3,perl=TRUE)
>
> test4<-strsplit(test3,split=';')
>
> test5<- data.frame(matrix(test4[[1]],ncol=9,
> byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
>
> colnames(test5)[1:8]<-test5[1,2:9]
>
> test5<-test5[-1,]

the output:

> test5
>
> ```
> [S1]    [E1] [S2] [E2] [LEN 1] [LEN 2] [% IDY] [TAGS]                 X9
> ```
>
> 2  959335  959806  169  640     472     472   80.84 LmjF.34 ULAVAL LtaPseq521
>
> 3  322990  324081 1436  342    1092    1095   83.86 LmjF.12 ULAVAL LtaPseq501
>
> 4  324083  324327  245    1     245     245   91.84 LmjF.12 ULAVAL LtaPseq501
>
> 5 1097873 1098325  892  437     453     456   76.75 LmjF.32 ULAVAL LtaPseq491
>
> 6 1098566 1098772  207    4     207     204   75.60 LmjF.32 ULAVAL LtaPseq491

Answer (score 0):

In this way is not simple with R.
If you are using UNIX, they are simple scripts (like in awk) to converts also large files before import it (i use this tecnique).